# Access pre-compiled functions within a class C++/11

Tags: c++, shell, clang

Sorry if the title is misleading, I'm currently looking for solutions to the following:

I'm developing a library, for other people to use. They have to follow a strict design concept and the way they structure any additional features within the library. They all use Linux and (Vim) and as such as are allowed to use terminal commands (i.e to be able to compile etc..) and we all use clang as a compiler.

My question is this: Let's suppose I write a function called: "checkCode":

```
    template<typename T>
    void checkCode(T&& codeSnippet)
    {
       //// code 
    }
```

I want to make this function run so whenever they type "checkCode" in a terminal this function is therefore called. I know using clang thy have similar functionality, however, this is understandable as you're using the whole of clang. So:

1) Is it possible to just compile a class, and then access each of the functions through 
the .dylab | .so file?

2) Might it be a better idea, or, better to take a copy of the source of clang, add this functionality and role it out to those using and contributing to the library? This would be like an additional add-on to clang?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that exactly the purpose of dynamic libraries?

Comment: If you want to be able to run a program from the command-line, you need to create an executable. So you need a function called `main`, and the executable clang generates (under the name you specify for the `-o` argument) will perform the actions defined in `main`. If `main` calls `checkCode`, then that's what the program will do. There is no way to run a function defined in a library directly by entering its name on the command line.

Comment: I'm not really sure, but are you asking for a [unit testing framework](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/)?

Comment: `checkCode` is not a function and leaves no trace in object files or libraries. Assuming you know how to overcome this, what kind of argument do you want to pass to it and how do you enter it from the command line? You probably don't want to fork clang in any case. You may want to provide python interface for your library instead.

Comment: @n.m. Hey thank you for the reply. Ideally, I wanted to fork clang and make additions to this in order to be able to learn, and hopefully contribute to an open source project.. What are your thoughts on this? I know there are other tasks to do and this is probably already been implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use one executable and symbolic links to it like busybox:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string programName = argv[0];
    size_t lastSlash = programName.find_last_of('/');
    if(lastSlash != string::npos)
        programName = programName.substr(lastSlash + 1);
    if(programName == "function_1")
    {
        function_1();
        return 0;
    }
    if(programName == "function_2")
    {
        function_2();
        return 0;
    }
    // ...
    // normal main code
    return 0;
}
```